Customizing push notification design from FCM for Android/iOS
How am I able to customize the design of the push notification received from FCM?
FCM states that if app is backgrounded/killed and it contains a notification payload, it will automatically be displayed in the system tray. I observed this behaviour on both Android and iOS.
Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive
The payload documentation states that Android can specify an icon, but the icon must already be a drawable resource in the app files, and iOS does not even give the option to include an icon in the payload
Android payload docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages
APNS payload docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/generating-a-remote-notification
I have tried to use the onMessageReceived on Android, but the function itself is not called when the app is killed, so I am not able to intercept the notification to display my own. However, Facebook is able to customize the design of their notification as shown in the image below by putting the icon on the left of the text, which does not follow notification anatomy stated in the documentation. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications#Templates

